# Coding index match to search multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I need to search for a number in multiple columns, then return the information in another cell. Here is a sample table:

[image: Sample table.]

I would like to keep the names on the left and the meets on the top. Additional names and meets will be added at a later time.

On a separate tab, I use the function:

```
=SMALL('100M'!B2:D5,1)
```

To locate the smallest number in the table. I now need to search the table for the result of the function above and return the name of the person. I know the index/match:

```
=index('100M'!$A$2:$D$5,match($B$2,'100M'!$D$2:$D$5,0),1)
```

This will work if I specify the exact column. I need to search through every column to match the Small number, then return the individuals name.

Answer (score 0):

Create a user defined function

```
Function GetMinName() As String

    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim minValue As Double
    Dim minValueCell As Range
    
    ' Define the data range
    Set dataRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:D5")
        
    ' Find the minimum value in the data range
    minValue = WorksheetFunction.min(dataRange)
        
    ' Find the first cell containing minimum value
    Set minValueCell = dataRange.Find(minValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
    
    ' Return the name in col 1 of the row containing the min value.
    GetMinName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(minValueCell.Row, 1)

End Function
```

This is the formula you put in the cell on the other sheet.

```
=GetMinName()
```

Comment: Awesome!  Is there an easy way to convert the user defined function to use in Google Sheets?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Google sheets. I have added the tag to your question and maybe someone can tell you.

Comment: Thanks.  Is it an easy adjustment to switch the search from the lowest to the second lowest or third lowest?

Comment: Use WorksheetFunction.small instead of WorksheetFunction.min. You should also look at the documentation for the [Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) function to handle the case when the same score appears more than once in the table.

Comment: Is there a simple one or two line code I can add to return the second name of the duplicate score; or do I need to stick with an If loop?

Comment: I have run into an unforeseen problem.  If I have the cells formatted as a time, the function will not return the value in the first cell.  Any suggestions on how too correct for this?  @Nicholas Hunter